# PHP extending Exception breaks getMessage

Tags: php, exception

When declaring a custom exception, e.g:

```
final class TestMeException extends Exception {}
```

It, somehow, breaks the getMessage() functionality, causing it to always return null. Meaning:

```
$e1 = new Exception('working');
$e2 = new TestMeException('not working');
print($e1->getMessage()); // prints: working
print($e2->getMessage()); // prints: null
```

Does anyone know what is going on here?

Comment: WFM https://3v4l.org/T116T

Comment: Me 2 https://eval.in/637023

Comment: @JonStirling So is it a problem with my specific version?

Comment: More likely something else is happening in your code.

Comment: @Guy just make absolutely sure you're not overriding the constructor in `TestMeException` . or if you are that you're calling `parent::__construct($message)`

Comment: @apokryfos I checked this out, also tried to override the constructor and call the parent constructor with the message, that did not work. It is in a huge project, so probably someone has broken something :/

Comment: It's more likely someone has broken something than PHP itself being broken.

Answer (score 0):

You guys were right. The problem appeared when mocking the exception via Autobahn Testsuite, without whitelisting the new exception class (by default it stubs out everything but the class under test and a list of whitelisted classes/functions).

Answer (score 0):

Try to extend with \Exception my be there are some problem with dependency and also make sure that your php version is > 5.2

I just used your code and every think works fine for me.